# Conversion from string "." to type 'Decimal' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

I have a unit converter written in Visual Basic, using Visual Studio 2013. The program is working fine until the user's initial input is a decimal point. I get this error message: Conversion from string "." to type 'Decimal' is not valid. How can I get this program to accept a decimal point as the initial input from the user without the program crashing? Code is below.

```
Private Function GetLength1(ByVal decLengthUnit1 As Decimal) As Decimal

Dim decResult1 As Decimal

If cboUnitType.SelectedItem = "Length" Then

    ' converts kilometer to...
    If cbo1.SelectedItem = "Kilometer" Then
        If cbo2.SelectedItem = "Kilometer" Then
            decResult1 = txtUnit1.Text
        ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Meter" Then
            decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 1000)
        ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Centimeter" Then
            decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 100000)
        ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Millimeter" Then
            decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 1000000)
        ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Mile" Then
            decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 0.621371191)
        ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Yard" Then
            decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 1093.613297)
        ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Foot" Then
            decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 3280.83989)
        ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Inch" Then
            decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 39370.07868)
        End If
    End If
End If

Return decResult1.ToString().Trim("0") ' this is where I convert the data back to a string with some formatting
End Function


Private Sub txtUnit1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles      txtUnit1.TextChanged

    ' convert string to numeric data type
    Decimal.TryParse(txtUnit1.Text, decUnit1) ' this is where I convert user input to decimal data type

    ' handle String.Empty, or negative sign
    If txtUnit1.Text = "" OrElse txtUnit1.Text = "-" Then
        txtUnit2.Text = ""

    ElseIf cboUnitType.SelectedItem = "Length" Then
        suppressTextBox2TextChanged = True
        txtUnit2.Text = GetLength1(decUnit1)
        suppressTextBox2TextChanged = False

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: "User's initial input is a `.`". Can you not check the text for that value, and convert it? Or set the value to zero, then do `On Error Resume Next`, and then the conversion - if no error, then the value gets overwritten, otherwise it will be zero.

Comment: Which line in your code is causing the problem?

Comment: @Floris - I am already attempting to convert it with the TryParse method, but I'm getting the error. What do you suggest I convert it with?

Comment: @EmmadKareem - This is where the program stops: Return decResult1.ToString("N").Trim("0")

Comment: Zack, did you get it to work?

Comment: @KayNelson - No, it isn't working yet. It works fine until I try to format the string with .ToString().Trim("0"). If I leave that out completely, it works but then I have unwanted trailing zeros and can't specify the amount of precision I want.

Comment: Is the issue that you cannot format the number with the correct number of digits? Could you give an example of what you want : "input = this string; output desired = that string"? You might be able to use `Format()`

Comment: @Floris - No, the problem lies when the user enters a zero or a decimal point instead of an integer greater than zero, the program throws an error that states: Conversion from string "." to type 'Decimal' is not valid. It doesn't do this if the user inputs any integer greater than zero for the very first number that they put in to be calculated. Everything is fine as long as the user input equals 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9 for the first digit entered in the text box. The program stops if the user enters 0, or ".".

Comment: Still trying to understand what you mean by "first digit". Is this "the first time the user enters a number", or "the first character in the input"? Example: will entering `0123` or `.123` give an error? Or only `.` by itself? What does something like `myString = ".123" : myDecimal = CDec(myString)` do? Does that throw an error too? Usually it is a good idea to reduce your problem to the smallest possible piece of code - it is then easier to understand, debug, and get help.

Comment: @Floris - My "first digit" means the first character in the input. You see, my unit converter doesn't use a button to calculate. It calculates as the user types in the number they wish to be converted. Therefore, when the user wants 55 millimeter converted, the program would convert 5 first, then as the second 5 is entered, the program would finally calculate 55.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is set to return to a Decimal value

```
Private Function GetLength1(ByVal decLengthUnit1 As Decimal) As Decimal
```

You can either change that to As String

```
Private Function GetLength1(ByVal decLengthUnit1 As Decimal) As String
```

Or you can change the Return

```
Return Ctype(decResult1.ToString().Trim("0"), Decimal)
```

It could also be that the `Decimal`  expects a `,` instead of `.` I think it has to do with the Culture settings you have. Then you could change the values you have written or do a `REPLACE`

`Replace(decResult1.ToString().Trim("0"),".",",")`

EDIT

You could also try to change the `txtUnit2.Text = GetLength1(decUnit1)`

Change it to  `txtUnit2.Text = GetLength1(decUnit1).ToString().Trim("0")` and remove the .Trim from inside the Function.

Now you are amending the .Text for the Textbox, then its using the allready obtained `Decimal` value.

Comment: I replaced the return type to String as you suggested and the program is accepting zero and decimal point as an initial input from the user. Thank you for that. Now, I am having issues formatting the string. I want to trim the trailing zeros after the decimal point without trimming zeros from a whole. What do you suggest for my formatting, and should I do the formatting in the function or in the TextChanged event?

Comment: Ok, give my EDIT part a try!

Comment: Okay, I did that and the program is still working. However, zeros before the decimal are being trimmed if there isn't a value past the decimal point. For example: Converting 1 Kilometer to Centimeter is giving me the result of 1 instead of 100000, but Converting 1.0 Kilometer to Centimeter is giving me the correct 100000 but with an unwanted decimal point at the end. The result looks like this: (100000.).

Answer (score 0):

If you have situations where an error occurs, you can often do the following:

```
val = 0
On Error Resume Next
val = someStatementThatMayCauseAnError
On Error Goto 0       ' turns error handling off again
```

This will return `0` for any inputs that could not be parsed.

Of course you could also use error handling to tell the user to try again:

```
On Error Goto whoops
myString = contentsOfTextBox
val = convert(myString)
Exit Function
whoops:
MsgBox "Cannot convert " & myString & "; please try again"
End Function
```

Finally - you could explicitly test for the string that gives trouble. But if you have a valid string that causes a problem, it may be that the problem is with your parsing function. Is there an issue with decimal points vs commas, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: I was trying to come up with some code for number validation for my own learning just before you posted your question and I got this far, I would not say it is fully tested, but I did not catch bugs so far:

```
Class Program
    Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())
        'For testing, culture string nl-BE allows , as a decimal separator

        Dim d As Decimal = CheckNum(".", String.Empty)
        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString())
        Console.Read()
    End Sub



    Private Shared Function CheckNum(parm_toParseStr As String, parm_cultureName As String) As Decimal
        'Convert the string sent to decimal value and raise an exception if conversion falils
        'Expects string to validate and culture name (e.g. en-US). If culture name not passed, current is used
        'Takes care of the missing feature in try parse, namely when a string of only "." is passed, tryparse
        ' does not convert it to 0.

        Dim style As NumberStyles
        Dim culture As CultureInfo
        Dim result As Decimal

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(parm_cultureName) Then
            parm_cultureName = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name
        End If

        'for style see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
        style = NumberStyles.Number Or NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign
        culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(parm_cultureName)

        parm_toParseStr = parm_toParseStr.Trim()

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(parm_toParseStr) Then
            parm_toParseStr = "0"
        End If

        ' Gets a NumberFormatInfo associated with the passed culture.
        Dim nfi As NumberFormatInfo = New CultureInfo(parm_cultureName, False).NumberFormat
        If parm_toParseStr = "+" OrElse parm_toParseStr = "-" OrElse parm_toParseStr = nfi.CurrencyDecimalSeparator Then
            '+ - and decimal point
            parm_toParseStr = "0"
        End If

        'for tryparse see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2
        If [Decimal].TryParse(parm_toParseStr, style, culture, result) Then
            Return result
        Else
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("Could not convert the passed value of:{0}", parm_toParseStr)
        End If

    End Function
End Class
```